# Extend WP Page Builder Editor Width

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP Page Builder plugin in my WordPress installation and I am editing the contents through frontend. Is it possible to increase the width of the frontend sidebar of the "WP Page Builder" widget? So, I can edit the text more easily.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading my answer.
Arun so far I have used many page builders in WordPress including Divi, Elementor, Ocean WP and their width can be adjusted using a small arrow which appears when hovering the mouse over its sidebar. Try this or do let me know if you are facing the same issue?
Another solution is to manually set the width in theme editor. Moreover, I have searched for this problem and come up with the answer that, this option is not available because it provides hand-on editing the text for mobile / tablet / laptop screen using the three options appearing at bottom.

Thanks for your time :)